# Is MySQL Polygon datatype better than storing polygon as a JSON object (text)?

Tags: mysql, json, polygon

I retrieve my polygons from the UI in this specific format:

```
[0] => [
    [0] => [X, Y],
    [1] => [X2, Y2],
    [2] => [X3, Y3],
    [3] => [X, Y]
],
[1] => [
    [0] => ... 
]
```

From my understanding, MySQL Polygon datatype hold data this way :

```
Polygon((X Y, X1 Y1, X2 Y2, X3 Y3, X Y))
```

What are the benefits of storing them as MySQL Polygons instead of just storing them as a serialized JSON object?

Keeping them in a JSON Object saves me the hassle of re-creating the array structure once I query the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary advantage will be if you actually want to perform geometric operations on those polygons *within the database*, or perform searches based on the polygon coordinates.

If you're just using the DB as a store, with some other column as the retrieval key, then you might as well store them in JSON.